# Error The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I got he problem when I try to write code for detail chat page. I try to wrap my appBar with `PreferredSize` but it's not working and then the debug console return the error message like this

```
37:15: Error: The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'.
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
 - 'PreferredSizeWidget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/preferred_size.dart' ('../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/preferred_size.dart').
      appBar: header(),
              ^
```

**This is the code**

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

import "../../theme.dart";

class DetailChatPage extends StatelessWidget{
  const DetailChatPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget header() {
      return PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor1,
          title: Row(
            children: [
              Image.asset("assets/image_shop_logo_online.png", width: 50, height: 50,),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 12,
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Shoe Store", style: primaryTextStyle.copyWith(fontWeight: medium),)
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          elevation: 0,
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor3,
      appBar: header(),
    );
  }
}
```

How I can fix that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assigned a Widget To AppBar so you have to change the function return type to PreferredSize

```dart
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

import "../../theme.dart";

class DetailChatPage extends StatelessWidget{
  const DetailChatPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  // build function
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor3,
      appBar: header(),
    );
  }
  // AppBar function
  // change function return type from Widget To PreferredSize
  PreferredSize header() {
      return PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor1,
          title: Row(
            children: [
              Image.asset("assets/image_shop_logo_online.png", width: 50, height: 50,),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 12,
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Shoe Store", style: primaryTextStyle.copyWith(fontWeight: medium),)
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          elevation: 0,
        ),
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Heii Duck, it's work!!  thanks for your answer!!  I appreciate it!!